# Appropriate use of Page Public Content Access

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are applying for the Page Public Content Access permission. We want to make our submission as comprehensive as possible, but not sure what Facebook is looking for.  We are aggregating local stories from local organizations to publish on town specific pages on our site. We will use the app to scroll various local organizations and pull stories for us to review and determine if it is valuable to a specific local town.

We are currently performing this task manually, as seen in this example:
https://news.hamlethub.com/newtown/events/45698-newtown-chamber-presents-pandemics-pocketbooks-via-zoom-on-wednesday
https://www.facebook.com/events/340344066841280/

The permission will allow us to provide more information to local communities.

Is this an appropriate use of this permission? Do you know what criteria Facebook is looking for in order to grant a publisher this permission?